# How can I change the location of an .InstallState file in a Visual Studio generated MSI

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation

I have an MSI file that I have created using a Visual Studio Setup Project.  The installed generates an .InstallState file in the application directory.  Is there a way to have this file generated in a different location rather than the default location?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the value of InstallStateDir.
You need to override the Commit/Install/Rollback/Uninstall and set the value of InstallStateDir (I.E. Context["InstallStateDir"] = @"c:\mydir")
.

Answer (score 1):

This should also work by specifying /InstallStateDir="c:\myfolder" from the commandline (see KB946503). However, InstallContext is converting all parameter names to lowercase which breaks the following code from AssemblyInstaller, expecting to find the mixed case parameter name:

```
private string GetInstallStatePath(string assemblyPath)
{
    string str2 = base.Context.Parameters["InstallStateDir"];
    assemblyPath = Path.ChangeExtension(assemblyPath, ".InstallState");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str2))
    {
        return Path.Combine(str2, Path.GetFileName(assemblyPath));
    }
    return assemblyPath;
}
```

Setting `Context["InstallStateDir"]` would possibly work for saving the state; however, as the state is loaded before `Uninstall` can modify the context, this is no viable solution until Microsoft fixes the above `AssemblyInstaller.GetInstallStatePath` method.

Comment: Know this is really old but I've been struggling with changing InstallStateDir (works during install and file goes to my folder but commit cannot find the original file...) so it's still relevant I think.  This answer was useful but not correct I think.  

Parameters is a StringDictionary and that lowercases keys (InstallStateDir = installstatedir)  For me it's looking in the original place so I agree this logic is not kicking in properly but I don't think it's because of the array type lookup (sadly)